# Is there anyway to receive a transaction hash from a transaction that was signed by the keyring?

Tags: hash

I am creating an application and signing an extrinsic with a keypair using the keyring. I was wondering if I can receive the transaction hash somehow after it has been signed

Comment: can you provide source to your application? What libs are you using to sign? what keyring?

Comment: Please also checkout https://substrate.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask - better formed questions here will get you better answers :) Welcome to the community!

Comment: Basically I'm looking for something similar to ethers.providers.TransactionResponse from the ethers project but for polkadot. Something That I can pass a signed transaction or even a signature to and retrieve a transaction hash

Comment: I am using the polkadot SignPayload function and was wondering if I can retrieve the transaction hash from it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

```js
import { blake2AsHex } from '@polkadot/util-crypto';

/**
 * Derive the tx hash of a signed transaction offline.
 *
 * @param signedTx - The hex encoding of a signed transaction.
 */
export function getTxHash(signedTx: string): string {
    return blake2AsHex(signedTx, 256);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work as expected. See here: https://westend.subscan.io/extrinsic/10696943-2

I expected to get the exstrinsic hash: 0xb11b3c5e7ef8efb518de8f0b6ca0107d06a47c6da949cd39ef40a76753c87ff8
But I ended up getting this extrinsic hash:
0x0fb3c429f27ffe991796ce594525eeac301a16a2f0ccd4f4caec2979332feadd
From the following signature: 0x85af7c6a21502dbdbd123596d804ad5eba1343d9c61128c7f96bb719887081ba5953519d68e8a9a2ff853c3d656a1406f2e814b456fcd983fa1c853fa62f3a03

Any ideas?

Comment: You need the entire extrinsic, not just the signature. You can see how Sidecar does it: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-api-sidecar/blob/992b458/src/services/blocks/BlocksService.ts#L368